# Separating elements in a XML into separate files

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a XML file that has a lot of nested topic elements. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic id="topic-1">
    <title>ADBT</title>

    <para>The program executes a database request by using the ADBT
        library. The ADBT library prepares
        the request and calls an ODBC driver
        or a native API.  
    </para>

    <topic id="topic_wom_eqy_ev">
        <title>Establishing a connection</title>
        <para>
            In order to use a database with ADBT, the first step to be taken
            is
            to establish a
            connection.
        </para>

    </topic>
    <topic id="topic_dsw_gqy_ev">
        <title>Querying a database</title>
        <para>Querying a database involves a number of stages.</para>
        <topic id="topic_ljf_isy_ev">
            <title>Stage one: create a query</title>
            <para> A new query (ADBT_Select object) can only be created starting
                from a previously
                established connection. A query is created using
                the CreateSelect method in two
                different
                ways:
            </para>
        </topic>
    </topic>

</topic>
```

I want each of the topics to be separated into a new XML file with the filename same as title. If a topic contains another topic, that topic will be a separate file and the parent topic will be a separate file with the contents excluding the child topic. For example in this case there will be four files as output with the following content:

Number 1:

```
<topic id="topic-1">
        <title>ADBT</title>

        <para>The program executes a database request by using the ADBT
            library. The ADBT library prepares
            the request and calls an ODBC driver or a native API.  
        </para>
    </topic>
```

Number 2:

```
<topic id="topic_wom_eqy_ev">
        <title>Establishing a connection</title>
        <para>
            In order to use a database with ADBT, the first step to be taken is
            to establish a
            connection. 
        </para>     

    </topic>
```

Number 3:

```
<topic id="topic_dsw_gqy_ev">
        <title>Querying a database</title>
        <para>Querying a database involves a number of stages.</para>
</topic>
```

Number 4:

```
<topic id="topic_ljf_isy_ev">
            <title>Stage one: create a query</title>
            <para> A new query (ADBT_Select object) can only be created starting
                from a previously
                established connection. A query is created using the CreateSelect method in two
                different
                ways:
            </para>
            </topic>
```

I have written few functions but I am not able to figure out how to separate the multilevel nested topics.

Comment: Do you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 so that you can use `xsl:result-document` to write several files?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you want to do is:

- read the XML using the XML reader of your choice
- get all the `<topic>` elements within the document recursively
- for every `<topic>` element, create a copy of that element (probably a new document for each one with the root of it being the `<topic>` element), copying all the children from the original but the children that have tagName = `topic`. This guarantees that the recursive calls will not yield overlapping elements
- for each of such created `Document`s, serialize it into a file using the XML writer of your choice

So, for a schematic code:

```
Document document = readXMLDocument(...);
List<Element> topicElements = readTopicElementsRecursively(document);
List<Document> splitTopicDocuments = new ArrayList<>();
for (Element el : topicElements) {
    Document doc = copyElementWithoutTopicChildren(el);
    splitTopicDocuments.add(doc);
}
writeTopicDocuments(splitTopicDocuments);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using XSLT 2.0 as available for Java with Saxon 9 you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//topic">
            <xsl:result-document href="topic{position()}.xml">
                <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
            </xsl:result-document>          
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="topic"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Martin. Need your input for a different set of question. Can you please help  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993864/match-and-merge-in-xslt-with-optional-nodes

Comment: To make the file name the same as the topic title (as requested) you can do `href="{title}.xml"`, though it's slightly questionable as href is supposed to be a URI and spaces in URIs aren't really allowed; it will also cause an error if titles are not unique.